# Google dataflow: AvroIO read from file in google storage passed as runtime parameter

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-functions, avro, apache-beam, google-cloud-platform

I want to read Avro files in my dataflow using java SDK 2
I have schedule my dataflow using cloud function which are triggered based on the files uploaded to the bucket.

Following is the code for options:

```
ValueProvider <String> getInputFile();
void setInputFile(ValueProvider<String> value);
```

I am trying to read this input file using following code:

```
PCollection<user> records = p.apply(
    AvroIO.read(user.class)
    .from(String.valueOf(options.getInputFile())));
```

I get following error while running the pipeline:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find any files matching RuntimeValueProvider{propertyName=inputFile, default=gs://test_bucket/user.avro, value=null}
```

Same code works fine in case of TextIO.
How can we read Avro file which is uploaded for triggering cloud function which triggers the dataflow pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Please try `...from(options.getInputFile()))` without converting it to a string.

For simplicity, you could even define your option as simple string:

```
   String getInputFile();
   void setInputFile(String value);
```

Comment: No I cant use simple String here.
I want to pass the input file at runtime.


when I am using options.getInputFile()
getting incompatible types error.


from expects input as a String.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use simply `from(options.getInputFile())`: `AvroIO` explicitly supports reading from a `ValueProvider`.

Currently the code is taking `options.getInputFile()` which is a `ValueProvider`, calling the Java`toString()` function on it which gives a human-readable debug string `"RuntimeValueProvider{propertyName=inputFile, default=gs://test_bucket/user.avro, value=null}"` and passing that as a filename for `AvroIO` to read, and of course this string is not a valid filename, that's why the code currently doesn't work.

Also note that the whole point of `ValueProvider` is that it is placeholder for a value that *is not known* while constructing the pipeline and will be supplied later (potentially the pipeline will be executed several times, supplying different values) - so extracting the value of a `ValueProvider` at pipeline construction time is impossible by design, because there is no value. At runtime though (e.g. in a `DoFn`) you can extract the value by calling `.get()` on it.

Comment: Hi
I tried using options.getInputFile(), but it gives following error.
incompatible types: 

org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.lang.String

following is the code :

`PCollection<user> records = p.apply(
              AvroIO.read(user.class)
                      .from(options.getInputFile()));`

Comment: Oh indeed, seems that the from(ValueProvider) version was added only in 2.2.0 which is currently going through the release process. You can either use version 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT, or as a workaround meanwhile you can use the internal class that normally shouldn't be used directly: p.apply(Read.from(AvroSource.from(options.getInputFile()).withSchema(user.class)))

Comment: `p.apply(Read.from(AvroSource.from(options.getInputFile()).wi‌​thSchema(user.class)‌​))` 

With this also getting the same incompatible types error.

This is from AvroSource code:
`public static AvroSource<GenericRecord> from(String fileNameOrPattern)`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - looked at the wrong github tab... Yeah, you're going to need to use 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: For now, can you try `from(options.getInputFile().get())`?